# Operator norm of semigroup operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $P_{t}$ be a self-adjoint operator such that $P_{t+s}=P_{t}P_{s}$. I want to show that 
$$\|P_{t}\|_{1\to \infty}\leq \|P_{t/2}\|_{1\to 2}\|P_{t/2}\|_{2\to \infty}.$$ 
For that, I am trying to prove that $$\|P_{t}f\|_{\infty}\leq \|P_{t/2}\|_{1\to 2}\|P_{t/2}\|_{2\to \infty}\|f\|_{1}$$ 
using that
$$\|P_{t}f\|_{\infty}=\sup_{g}\frac{(P_{t}f, g)}{\|g\|_{1}}=\sup_{g}\frac{(P_{t/2}f, P_{t/2}g)}{\|g\|_{1}},$$ 
but then I am stuck. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\|Ax\|_{q} \leq \|A\|_{p \to q}\|x\|_p$.  Thus,
$$
\|P_tf\|_\infty = \|P_{t/2}(P_{t/2}f)\|_\infty \\
\leq \|P_{t/2}\|_{2 \to \infty} \|P_{t/2}f\|_2 \\
\leq 
\|P_{t/2}\|_{2 \to \infty} \|P_{t/2}\|_{1 \to 2} \|f\|_1
$$

Comment: Ah, that was much more easy than I thougt, thank you!